# Magento2 - Getting error Could not find a matching version of package After submitting in packagist.org

Tags: magento2, composer

I have Created New Module and uploaded in github.

Module Name : **vrajeshpatel4u/helloworld**

Url : https://github.com/vrajeshpatel4u/helloworld/

Packagist Url : https://packagist.org/packages/vrajeshpatel4u/helloworld

Below command I have tried still getting error : `Could not find a matching version of package vrajeshpatel4u/helloworld. Check the package spelling, your version constraint and that the package is available in a stability which matches your minimum-stability (stable).`

`git add .`
`git commit -m 'initial commit'`
`git push origin master`
`git tag 1.0.0`
`git push origin --tags`

Here is the `composer.json`

```
{
    "name": "vrajeshpatel4u/helloworld",
    "description": "Simple Hello World Module for Magento 2",
    "type": "magento2-module",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "license": [
        "OSL-3.0",
        "AFL-3.0"
    ],
    "authors": [
        {
            "name": "Vrajesh Patel"
        }
    ],
    "minimum-stability": "dev",
    "require": {
        "php": "~7.1.3||~7.2.0||~7.3.0"
    },
    "autoload": {
        "files": [
            "registration.php"
        ],
        "psr-4": {
            "V4U\\Helloworld\\": ""
        }
    }
}
```

For installing Modules I have tried below commands :

`composer require vrajeshpatel4u/helloworld`

`composer require vrajeshpatel4u/helloworld:dev-main`

Any one help me to fix the issue?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You using using composer 1 . You need to use composer 2 for your package.

Note is showing on your page `This package is not installable via Composer 1.x, please make sure you upgrade to Composer 2+. Read more about our Composer 1.x deprecation policy.`

I just tried with composer 2 and it worked. You can check number of install at https://packagist.org/packages/vrajeshpatel4u/helloworld